# What is the kernel syntax when booting from ZFS?

Tags: freebsd, grub2, zfs

I'm trying to write a `grub.cfg` completely from scratch that will boot one of several FreeBSD systems off of a single ZFS pool named `tank` with a set of root file systems named `root1`, `root2`, `root3`.

When I look at the official GRUB2 docs, there is one example in 5.3

```
menuentry "FreeBSD" {
          insmod zfs
          search --set=root --label freepool --hint hd0,msdos7
          kfreebsd /freebsd@/boot/kernel/kernel
          kfreebsd_module_elf /freebsd@/boot/kernel/opensolaris.ko
          kfreebsd_module_elf /freebsd@/boot/kernel/zfs.ko
          kfreebsd_module /freebsd@/boot/zfs/zpool.cache type=/boot/zfs/zpool.cache
          set kFreeBSD.vfs.root.mountfrom=zfs:freepool/freebsd
          set kFreeBSD.hw.psm.synaptics_support=1
}
```

I figured that `freepool` is likely the ZFS pool name which I would replace with `tank`. I *suspect* that the `x@y` syntax is the way to refer to a file `y` on the file system `x` of the pool selected by the `search`. Then I would replace this with `/root1@/boot/kernel/kernel`. Sadly, the `x@y` syntax is undocumented and I don't want to *just try with fingers crossed*, but rather *understand and know what I'm doing*. Can anyone shed light on this?

Comment: Maybe for comparison the menu entry in these last forum [posts](https://forums.freebsd.org/viewtopic.php?&t=25164)... the "@" is "alone" there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, anything before @ is the ZFS dataset name (aka filesystem name) with a / prefix. For example the file `/boot/kernel/kernel` in file system `zroot/ROOT/freebsd-10` can be refered with `/zroot/ROOT/freebsd-10@/boot/kernel/kernel` in GRUB.

You can also learn this by using the GRUB command line (pressing `c` if you are in the GRUB menu). ZFS support in GRUB 2 supports directory listing, so you can use `ls` command or TAB to explore this internal structure of ZFS in GRUB 2.